# Email current record with layout via Apex

Tags: apex, email, page-template

I'm creating a messaging class where I want to send an email from a record. I'm not sending to a user/contact/lead so I can't use a template and my record has over 100 fields on it so I'd rather not have to code it all out as a string.

Is there any way for me to email the current record formatted to coincide with the page layout of that record, without having to code everything by hand?

I believe this is possible with a visualforce page but would love it if I could generate it from a standard page layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think You can't do this without writing html/VF template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a visualforce page and adding `<apex:details>` tag in the page. Basically it will show the details page layout in visualforce page. Then you can get the content of the page as PDF into the apex class using getContent() method. Finally you can attach the returned blob as attachment in email.

Comment: tag being `apex:detail` ?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, missed to mark tag as code type :(